# libpng15 static link issues

Tags: linux, static-linking, libpng

I've encountered an issue whilst developing my own application based on *libpng* (1.5 version).

Long story short, I need to static link this library but I keep getting **'undefined reference'** errors. I tried both extracting **libpng15.a** and adding its content to my library as well as linking with a gcc command.

My gcc command:

`gcc test.c librimg.a libz.a libpng15.a  -o test -std=c99 -lglfw -lGL -lGLU`

Errors I get:

```
libpng15.a(libpng15_la-png.o): In function `png_reset_crc':
/home/robin/Downloads/libpng-1.5.12/png.c:111: undefined reference to `crc32'
libpng15.a(libpng15_la-png.o): In function `png_calculate_crc':
/home/robin/Downloads/libpng-1.5.12/png.c:152: undefined reference to `crc32'
libpng15.a(libpng15_la-png.o): In function `png_reset_zstream':
/home/robin/Downloads/libpng-1.5.12/png.c:757: undefined reference to `inflateReset'
libpng15.a(libpng15_la-pngread.o): In function `png_create_read_struct_2':
/home/robin/Downloads/libpng-1.5.12/pngread.c:119: undefined reference to `inflateInit_'
libpng15.a(libpng15_la-pngread.o): In function `png_read_row':
/home/robin/Downloads/libpng-1.5.12/pngread.c:557: undefined reference to `inflate'
libpng15.a(libpng15_la-pngread.o): In function `png_read_destroy':
/home/robin/Downloads/libpng-1.5.12/pngread.c:1070: undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
libpng15.a(libpng15_la-pngrutil.o): In function `png_inflate':
/home/robin/Downloads/libpng-1.5.12/pngrutil.c:333: undefined reference to `inflate'
/home/robin/Downloads/libpng-1.5.12/pngrutil.c:362: undefined reference to `inflateReset'
libpng15.a(libpng15_la-pngrutil.o): In function `png_read_finish_row':
/home/robin/Downloads/libpng-1.5.12/pngrutil.c:3848: undefined reference to `inflate'
/home/robin/Downloads/libpng-1.5.12/pngrutil.c:3880: undefined reference to `inflateReset'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

(Note: I've compiled library from source and directory */home/robin/Downloads/libpng-1.5.12/* is a place where I extracted the archive.)

It's probably worth mentioning that I can link to a shared library without any difficulties:

`gcc test.c librimg.a -o test -std=c99 -lpng15 -lglfw -lGL -lGLU`

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: This could be because of the way the linker works. Try putting `libz` *after* `libpng` - the linker generally scans each library in turn, resolving symbols that are currently known to be unresolved. In your example, it processes `libz` before it knows that it needs anything from `libz`, because it hasn't seen `libpng` yet...

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve this issue by myself.

I copied all *libpng15.a* and *libz.a* to my project's directory and extracted them. Then I packed all objects files (including mine own) into one library (**.a*). This is working :)

Answer (score 0):

I had problem with creating qrencode executable (FUKUCHI Kentaro libqrencode) with staticaly linked libpng (version 1.5). I have resolved it thanks to your post by realizing I nned to link libz. So the solution is adding dynamic libz.

Here is my command line:

```
./configure --prefix=${TARGET_FOLDER} CFLAGS=-mmacosx-version-min=10.6 png_LIBS=/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.5.17/lib/libpng15.a LDFLAGS=/usr/lib/libz.dylib
```